# Should proposing a site have a higher threshold?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, site-proposal

In concept, I like the idea that most users can propose a site.  The problem is that I also like the "one proposal per user per day rule".

It would appear that the low threshold for site proposals is driving a number of proposals being made in the same day by different 'users'  with improbably similar profiles:

- Fostering a troll free stack overflow (Link not archived)
- The hunting of vampires (Link not archived)
- [https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3661/unanswerable-questions](https://web.archive.org/web/20100611073259/http://area51.stackexchange.com:80/proposals/3661/unanswerable-questions) (linked to archive)

Setting a higher bar for proposals than for voting might help protect against proposal noise.

Comment: Just a theory, but the pending "reset all voting data" change might be putting the breaks on legitimate site interactions for the moment...

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem might be limited to one individual. Perhaps an account suspension would be more effective.

Comment: I agree. Ban all users with sockpuppets!

Comment: Two individuals: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3767/boxedusers-meta-stackoverflow-com

Comment: This one (and its creator) more fully exhibits the symptoms described by the OP: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3857/fostering-a-troll-free-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Downvote away, but I found Evan's proposal to be the highlight of my day. Maybe it was a very dark day.