# Increase minimum rep for new proposals

Tags: feature-request, area-51, site-proposal, rep-requirement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should proposing a site have a higher threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52557/should-proposing-a-site-have-a-higher-threshold)

Some of the newest site proposals suggest their proposers have not only not used SOFU before (which is ok) but they also don't seem to know about it (which is a pity), see e.g. [.NET Framework](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12960/net-framework) and [Java Platform Micro Edition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12913/java-platform-micro-edition). I suggest a minimum rep of 75 (i.e. a connected account or a verified email plus at least 5 on-/off-topic votes for useful definition-phase questions).

Comment: Possible dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52557/should-proposing-a-site-have-a-higher-threshold

Comment: The guy who proposed the java me site, actually is a member of Stackoverflow, so he didn't propose it because he didn't know about Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think those proposals die before they reach beta. And if, by chance they make it, they'll not attract a community that is big enough to keep the site alive. So sooner or later, all questions from those sites would be migrated to SO anyway.

Comment: well, there's [Ubuntu](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu) and [Unix & Linux](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3924/unix-linux), both overlapping each other and most likely a subset of SU, yet they are in commitment-phase