# Increase Reputation Requirements for Creating a Proposal in Area 51

Tags: feature-request, reputation, area-51, site-proposal

Sometimes I get the strong impression that **the proposal creation process in Area 51 is mostly broken**.

New Users almost always create new proposals rather than search for and commit to similar existing proposals.

**For this reason I believe that Area 51 should raise the requirement for creating a proposal to between 400-500 rep points.**

IMHO many of the users that have 300 or less reputation typically are unaware of Area 51's systemic duplicate proposal issues.  By forcing new users to gain a little reputation first, they have to spend some time thinking about supporting similar proposals rather than rashly creating their own.

**Furthermore, Area 51 doesn't need more proposals, it needs less.** (At this point in time)

Unlike other sites that typically benefit from more questions and answers, Area 51 does not necessarily benefit from more proposals.  **This is because proposals that overlap with other proposals suck the energy out of each other and confuse both old and new users.**

Creating new proposal ideas is not very difficult for anyone, better that more experienced users be the ones behind this process.

Comment: I'm quite certain someone has requested this before...

Comment: @Adam Davis - I s*ck at finding duplicates here on meta, do you have any links?

Comment: @Adam, perhaps we should increase the reputation requirements for posting feature-requests in meta

Comment: @Juan Manuel - I'm sorry is this feature-request not to your liking?  Did I fumble some custom, again?

Comment: Nah, I'm just kidding. You're ok (i upvoted)

Comment: @Mark No, I'm being lazy today.  I'd say this is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52557/should-proposing-a-site-have-a-higher-threshold but I'm pretty sure we had such a question with much better answers about why it's important to allow even 1 rep users to submit proposals.

Comment: @Adam Davis - I would argue that this is a similar but different feature-request.  The argument and the implementation are both different.  To the other point, whatever their answers were, I've got an updated argument for them.  I would like to see the post if you ever find the link.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52557/should-proposing-a-site-have-a-higher-threshold.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I think that question might be slightly different, because its referring to the number of proposals.  Rather than directly talking about reputation requirements.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with this, but with a way smaller threshold.

**I think a requirement of 200 rep points would weed out 90% of duplicate proposals.**

200 could mean:

- 100 points from association with existing SE profile
- 50 points for verifying the email address
- 50 points for getting 10 votes on example questions - which I think is pretty easy, and is enough to make people familiar with Area 51

Here are some recent duplicate proposals, you can see for yourself they were proposed by people with less than 200 rep on Area51:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31044/symfony-framework
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31043/sap-solutions
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31039/minecraft
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31008/jquery

**As we have it now, the majority of new proposals are duplicates** - http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=newest - and they unnecessarily waste people's time for closing them.

Alternatively, at least don't show proposals from new users, until a moderator approves them.

Comment: I think 200 is probably good.

Answer (score -1):

Reputation on Area 51 is extremely hard to get if you're not the author of a successful proposal. Even experienced SE users often have barely more than the initial 151 you get for joining.

I don't think reputation on Area 51 is a useful filter. Most duplicate proposals never gain any momentum, and there is always the option of merging proposals.

Comment: Man, I just seeded a ton of questions in early  January and in a month I had 2000 points.  That's not to say they were bad questions.  Maybe I just have a knack for running my mouth, err fingers.

Comment: [almost] all my rep has come from questions

Comment: Hard to get? People are upvoting even poor questions in order to meet 40x10 requirement. If someone downvotes them, other will upvote to fill the gap, generating even more rep for asker.